# getting Amadeus API Error in WordPress : 403 forbidden, code: 35283

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation, amadeus

I'm new to Amadeus development. I'm using Amadeus Self service API's to get flights search from searched term. Everything used to work fine, but from today, if i call an api, I'm receiving error 403 forbidden.

> {
> "errors": [
> {
> "status": 403,
> "code": 35283,
> "title": "FORBIDDEN",
> "detail": "Incorrect user, no configuration found"
> }
> ] }

I have tried to with different api keys.

Any answers much appreciated.

Comment: What does code 35283 mean?

Comment: could not get any clue

Comment: Unfortunately the Flight Offers Search API is currently unstable. The technical team is working on providing a fix.